# os.path.join to create filename in python with datetime not working in mac

Tags: python, os.path

I am trying to generate a filename in python on mac to record data everyday so that the filename has date in filename. Please refer the command below.

```
oi_filename= os.path.join("markets","storage","oi_data_records_{0}.json".format(datetime.now().strftime(%d%m%Y)))
```

where markets is in Desktop and storage is in markets folder.

```
Error
  File "<ipython-input-20-e3a1aee3f506>", line 21
    oi_filename= os.path.join("markets","storage","oi_data_records_{0}.json".format(datetime.now().strftime(%d%m%y)))
                                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The basic idea is everyday a file to be created with full date in name so that the rest of program can park the data in the respective file.

Comment: Did you look at any of the examples?  `strftime` accepts a string.  A string is always enclosed in quotes.  Yours is not.  That's why you get a syntax error.

Comment: And seriously, you need to consider using "%y%m%d" instead.  That way, your files will sort in date order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't put the `%d%m%y` in a string.

```
oi_filename= os.path.join("markets","storage","oi_data_records_{0}.json".format(datetime.now().strftime(%d%m%Y)))
```

should be:

```
oi_filename= os.path.join("markets","storage","oi_data_records_{0}.json".format(datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotation marks for `strftime(%d%m%y)`. It should be `strftime('%d%m%y')`